# How to create asynchronous code in Flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

In my Code I get some User Input by TextFormFields and save them in a Map in Firestore. In the next step I want to take calculations with this data and show them the user in the same widget.
I think because of the delay by saving in database I need to wait till the data is saved. But how can I do this? Here is my Code where I want to wait:

```
  void validate() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      UserManager.userdata["userStats"][0]["userActivity"] = userActivity;
      savetoremote_dynamic(context);
      AppBuilder.of(context).rebuild();
    }
  }
```

This is the rebuild class, so that the UI gets updated:

```
class AppBuilderState extends State<AppBuilder> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context);
  }

  void rebuild() {
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

I want that as soon as the data is saved the Widget gets rebuild an the updated data is shown to the user, how to use async and await in this code?

Comment: you can use ChangeProvider and listeners

Comment: I thougt i need async, await and future, but i dont know how to use them

Comment: ChangeNotifier* 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Provider/Riverpod or any suitable State Management that fits you. Alternatively, You can use FutureBuilder to show indicator while loading data from FireStore or any other API.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what is the async code in your snippet.
However, in flutter a minimal pattern to update the gui based on the result of an async operation is this:

- in a flutter callback (for example ElevatedButton.onTap, or initState if the code is to be executed at startup; in your case it could be validate) call your method with the async code -for example `getUserDataFromFirestore()`- ***without await the result***. You can not usually mark flutter callback such as `validate()` with `async`.
- the method with the async operation, `getUserDataFromFirestore()`, can be marked with async, so inside it you can use `await future` instead of `future.then()` (but it is only syntactic sugar).

  When you got the asynchronous data, you value a variable, for example `userData`, and rebuild calling setState().
- In the build method, you check if `userData` is not null and then you can show the user data (for example with a collection if in the Column.children list).
- If the async operation has to be executed at startup (when the page load, or similar), FutureBuilder is very handy: instead of a nullable field such as `User? user`, you can declare a `Future<User>` field:

  In your State subclass:

  ```dart
  late Future<User> user;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = getUserDataFromFirestore();
  }

  Furure<User> getUserDataFromFirestore() async {
    //your async code; returns the user data
  }

  @override
  build(context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
       future: user,
       builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
         if (! asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
            //user data is not available.
            //returns a gui that does not display the user data
         } else {
            //user data is available..
         }
       } 
    );
  }
  ```

A simple example about a minimal async operation in flutter, using this pattern, is in this cookbook page:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data